# Is ϴ(n)/n = ϴ(1)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

I came across the following equation:

[image]

So is ϴ(n)/n (or ϴ(n)/(n+1)) = ϴ(1)? If yes then please help me understand the reason for that with an example.

Comment: would this be for the math. site ?

Comment: Hello! Mathematics questions are off-topic on StackOverflow. See the [help/on-topic] for what topics you can ask about hear. You may be able to ask this question on [Math.SE] StackExchange, but be sure to check their posting guidelines before asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programing question within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: This is more a computer science / algorithmic theory question than a math question.

Comment: @jxh I agree. I think the maths Stack Exchange might kind of turn their nose up at this question. Plus, I think Bhavesh wants some examples in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***ϴ(n)*** would represent algorithms of complexities such as ***n, 2n, 3n, 4n, etc.*** You can think of ***ϴ(n)*** as representing something like ***kn***, where ***k*** is a positive real number.

***kn/n*** is of course ***k*** which you can likewise think of as what ***ϴ(1)*** represents.

***kn/(n+1)*** converges on ***k*** as ***n->∞***. You can use L'Hopital's to confirm this.

If you're new to Big-Theta and Big-O it helps to read ***ϴ(n)*** as "on the order of n"; likewise, ***ϴ(n<sup>2</sup>),*** "on the order of n-squared"; and so on.

**Edit:**
Note, the tone of my answer is intentionally informal. The accurate conceptualization is to think about ***ϴ(n)*** in terms of bounding functions. See Paul Hankins comments below. While in day-to-day use I maintain the understanding above is helpful, I suggest you heed his advice and concern.

To ensure that at least some of his notes are represented here as well, I add that the formal definition of an O complexity is as follows:

> A function ***f(x)*** can be said to be ***O(g(x))*** if there exists ***|f(x)|
> <= Mg(x) ∀ x >= x<sub>0</sub>*** where ***M*** is a positive real number.

> ***ϴ(g(x))*** also satisfies ***|f(x)| >= Mg(x) ∀ x >= x<sub>0</sub>*** where ***M*** is a positive real number.

Hopefully, this isn't too much of a leap from the example above. You can now pose the question: is a function bounded by ***M<sub>a</sub>x*** divided by ***x*** bounded by ***M<sub>b</sub>(1)***?

Comment: This answer has upvotes and has been accepted, but it contains some things which I think are confusing even if the intent of the answer is to be helpful. Theta(n) is not something like kn - it's a set of functions whose magnitudes are (eventually) bounded above and below by linear functions. Theta(1) is not "essentially" a constant -- it's the set of functions whose magnitudes are eventually bounded above and below by constants. |cos(n)|n + 5n|sin(n)| is Theta(n) for example, but is not something like kn for any k.

Comment: I understand the intent of answers like this -- the actual definitions require some work to understand, and it's possible to get a feel for complexities by simplifying the notions until they're easy to grasp without much work. But simplified explanations that factually diverge from the actual definitions are at best only a stepping-stone to actual understanding, and in practice there's so much confusion around what complexity actual is that I think they're unhelpful.

Comment: I agree with you. For a precise understanding, it's better to think in terms of bounded functions. Perhaps it'd be best to write up an answer of that sort, then mine can be a stepping stone to yours.

Comment: Lmk, if that's closer to what you think is adequate.

Comment: I'm not going to engage further on this question, because I already said what I thought was important. I will say however that your definition of big-Theta is actually the definition of big-O.